# Can I use git-svn to clone a specific branch of a remote SVN repo and commit back to it?

Tags: git, svn, branch, git-svn

I have a very large codebase with many tags and branches on a remote SVN server.

I'd like to use git to clone a specific branch to work on, then eventually merge it back to the remote SVN. Is this possible? Most documentation I've seen doesn't directly say this is supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this works fine. You can just do `git svn clone https://svn.example.com/project/branches/somebranch/` and then use git-svn normally (i.e. `git svn rebase` to pull and `git svn dcommit` to push.)

Comment: Also check out the `-r` option, which can be used (with care) to only download partial history.

Comment: Thank you for that. I was overthinking the problem. This worked perfectly.